# Connecting PowerPivot to PostgreSQL database

Tags: excel, postgresql, odbc, powerpivot

When I try to connect PowerPivot PostgreSQL database(at the point when I need to "Choose how to import the data". When I choose to select from tables and views, I get error below. When I choose to write sql query and press on 'design' button, empty window opens up (it should open tables from database)), I get this error message:

```
"No tables were found in the data source. Check the connection information and login credentials."
```

I use "Connection to data source - Others (OLEDB/ODBC)". I have installed PostgreSQL ODBC driver. I use PostgreSQL ANSI driver (tried UNICODE, got the same error). When I test connection, it says "connection succeeded). Also If I use same connection to same database for Pivot Table, everything works and I can take any table from my database.

I use MS Office 2012 32 bit and PowerPivot is 32 bit too.

So I suppose no one got any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried having Postgres log all queries? You'll be able to see the real error that pg is returning to the ODBC driver. Just edit your postgresql.conf and change (or add) log_statement = all  and log_error_verbosity = verbose.  Then restart pg and try again.

Comment: Check the permissions for the login you are using to connect. You could verify if this is a permissions issue by connecting as SA. As obvious as this may be...

Answer (score 4):

Was having the same problem - successful connection but list of tables was empty. Only way I can import data is to select **"Write a query that will specify the data to import"** instead of "Select from a list of tables and views to choose the data to import." Slightly more tedious, but gets you access to the data :)

Basic Query:
**Select * from catalogname.tablename**

My tables were listed under a public schema within the catalog, so:
**Select * from catalogname.public.tablename**

Could not import a specific column, so this was my successful query to confirm connection and get access to data: **Select column1, column2, column 3 from catalogname.public.tablename**

Answer (score 3):

I investigated this problem. PostgreSQL ODBC driver contains some bugs and this is the reason of this error:

"No tables were found in the data source. Check the connection information and login credentials."

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a problem with the odbc driver for postgresql.  Did you install the 64 bit driver?  I would check on this and, in the meantime, I agree that you should try writing a query that will specify the data and see if that is a viable workaround.

Comment: This would probably work better as a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).